# copy the entries of a file within the file using awk in unix

Tags: unix, awk

i have a file and would like to copy some entries that satisfy certain conditions. 
For example

```
myfile
chr1 a b c
chr2 a b c
chr3 x y z
```

I would like to copy lines whose first column starts with chr1 and i want to copy it n times.

```
myfile
chr1 a b c
chr1 a b c
chr1 a b c
chr2 a b c
chr3 x y z
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would be fine?

`awk '{if ($1 == "chr1"){print; print;} print;}'`

It will print 2 more times the lines that start with `chr1`

...and with a for loop:

`awk '{if ($1 == "chr1"){ for(i=1;i<=2;i++){ print; } } print;}'`

ok, this should be it

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{
    while ((getline < "conditions") > 0){
        cond[$1] = $2
    }
}
{
    print;
    for (i=0; i<cond[$1]; ++i){
        print;
    }
}
```

given a file named "conditions" like this:

```
chr1 5
chr2 3
```

and your example (with chr1, chr2 etc on different lines) as an input

it'll print the chr1 line 6 times, the chr2 line 4 times and the chr3 line 1 time

Comment: Thanks that is excellent. Is it also possible to put this in a for loop? i have almost 1000 conditions. for example, i want to copy chr1 3 times, chr 2 four times etc.

Comment: awk should evaluate its program for every line that it receives in input, thus, if you can extract from somewhere (the line itself or somewhere else) the number of times you need to copy the line you should be golden... can you elaborate on your example?

Comment: Thanks a lot :) but one last question :) i have these conditions on a seperate file which tells me the condition and the number of times it needs to be repeated. e.g. chr1   3      chr2    5     chr3    5.  so i need to repeat the chr1 3 times, chr2 5 times and chr 3 5 times. they are many. is it possible to read these conditions from an external file? i might be asking too much from awk command?

Comment: from an awk one liner, yes :) but you can just save the code as an awk script... I'll try to write something down now

Comment: ok this is a stupid question but how do i run this code? i saved it as 'test' and the conditions as 'conditions'.

Comment: there's an helpful shebang at the top :) if you `chmod +x test` you can simply do `./test data` to execute it (assuming you saved your example input as a file called "data")

Comment: That is perfect. Thank you very very much :) all sorted now. best

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v chr1=a -v n=3 '{ print; } substr($0,0,1) == chr1 { for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) print; }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your comments in the berdario answer, I'd write:

```
awk '
  NR == FNR {
    cond[$1] = $2
    next
  }
  $1 in cond {
    for (i=1; i<cond[$i]; i++) print
  }
  { print }
' conditions filename
```